# Opera autocomplete in custome search engine

Tags: opera, autocomplete, search-engines

Some build-in search engine of Opera have auto-complete feature. How can I add these capability to my custom search engines? `

Comment: Do you mean *auto-suggest* or *auto-complete*? Auto-suggest is indeed depending on the actual search engine. And what Opera version and OS are you using?

Comment: @nixda I mean what you called it "auto-suggest". `Version
12.15 
Build
1748 
Platform
Win32 
System
Windows 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Opera extension [AutoComplete](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/autocomplete/) is what you are looking for.

```
This extension provides Autocomplete for the text input box. Data which was 
input previously can be shared with any sites. And presents words suggested 
by search engines.

= Features
* Complete from data you input before
* Complete from suggests by search engines
```

AutoComplete works together with auto suggested words from search engines. There are a couple of search engines out there which support auto suggest beside google, wikipedia and bing. But opera hasn't added them to their default *search.ini* file so far. Fortunately you can add them on your own.

You will find your *search.ini* file at one of these paths (after you have added a custom search engine)

- Installed mode: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera\search.ini`
- Portable mode: `..\Opera\profile\search.ini`

The highlighted part is the important part which can be added manually. The *Suggest URL* must be known. I found some *Suggest URLs* simply by googling around.

[image]

**tested list of Suggest URLs for Opera**

- Google: http://google.com/complete/search?q={SearchTerm}
- Google Images: http://www.google.com/complete/search?ds=i&output=firefox&q={SearchTerm}
- Youtube: http://www.google.com/complete/search?output=opera&q={SearchTerm}&ds=yt
- Bing: http://api.bing.net/osjson.aspx?Query={SearchTerm}
- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search={SearchTerm}&format=json
- Amazon: http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?method=completion&q={SearchTerm}&search-alias=aps&mkt=1

You find a good explanation how the *search.ini* works [on this blog](http://my.opera.com/SearchEdit/blog/search-ini-explainen).

Comment: Thanks. How can I create a simpe opera extension that add my site to search engine with auto-suggestion capability?

Comment: @PHPst I'm sorry. This is beyond my knowledge

Comment: @nixda : It doesn't work for original existing search engine : Opera 12.16 constantly screw my search engine list by overriding my search.ini with garbage *(duplicates search engines; google can't be called with the **g** key; deleted ones appear again... )*.